# Unable to combine my domain name and IP regex rules into a single rule

Tags: regex

I have the following regex expression:

```
^(((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$|(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$)
```

Which validates the following 7 domain name and IP address variations:

```
example.com
www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
65.98.157.52
```

However, I'm trying to also include these 2 variations:

```
http://65.98.157.52
https://65.98.157.52
```

I believe I need to move the IP part of the regex after the http(s) rules, but I can't figure out how to chain them together. I've been using a regex validator and I just can't make it cover all options.

Comment: Note there are more cases of valid protocol-and-host strings you still won't cover then, such as IPv6 addresses and Unicode domains. It may make more sense to just attempt to create a `new URL` (in case of JS - or the equivalent in your language, respectively) from it and see if it succeeds. (Of course there is the question what about path and query since you don't seem to allow those - how to check for those would again depend on the language in question - but my main point is to not try to reinvent the wheel but use existing functionality for it.)

Comment: Do you mean a literal IP address? Like `^(?:https?:\/\/65\.98\.157\.52|(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)(?:\.(?!$)|$)){4}|(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/.*)?)$`? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/tYMI9V/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If by literal you mean hard coded, then no, I'm trying to make it cover all IPs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an optional `http://` and `https://` at the start of the first alternative:

```py
^(?:(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)(?:\.(?!$)|$)){4}|(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/.*)?)$
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tYMI9V/2).

Note I merged some alternatives by making `s` after `http` optional.

Comment: Absolutely wonderful, my regex actually allowed some stuff that I didn't want to, but yours covers exactly what I want and nothing more!